# ¿Para que sirven los dos puntos (:) y la flecha (>) en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Necesito realizar un borrado de dos tablas que están relacionadas y viendo el hilo de esta [respuesta en stackoverflow anglosajón](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql/46885087). Me topo que en el problema del usuario @alex y la respuesta del usuario @cadman (que da solución al problema) utilizan el símbolo `>` y `:` en la clausula `where`, así:

```
DELETE p, pa
      FROM pets p
      JOIN pets_activities pa ON pa.id = p.pet_id
      WHERE p.order > :order
      AND p.pet_id = :pet_id
```

Realmente no entiendo por que lo usan así ¿Es posible que haga parte de la sintaxis del lenguaje que está usando en el backend?

Comment: lo que significa en cualquien ambito `<>` mayo y menor y `:` es una variable `:order y :pet_id`

Comment: Esto no tiene que ver directamente con mySQL, como con su uso desde algún lenguaje de programación y algún cliente o capa de conexión particular, que no has incluido en las etiquetas de la pregunta. Los `:` se utilizan generalmente para pasar _parámetros_ dentro de una consulta de base de datos. En este caso, hay dos parámetros, uno llamado `order` y otro `pet_id`. Desde el lenguaje de programación, generalmente, se asignarán valores a estos parámetros, que son una especie de _variable_ dentro de la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` es simplemente el operador mayor que, es decir, `id > 5` se lee id mayor que 5.

En cuanto al `:` es el caracter que indica [variables bindeadas](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-bindvariables/index.html#:%7E:text=A%20bind%20variable%20consists%20of,the%20SQL%20statement%20is%20executed.), es decir `:order` se está refiriendo a la variable `order` que tiene definida en algún lugar.